# Dynamic button background change

Tags: button, dynamic, highcharts

I wonder if this possible:
I have added my own button (see follow), and now I wonder if I can change button background color dynamically upon click.
The idea is to simulate a check box enable/disable.

```
  exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        buttons: {
            'realTimeButton': {
                id: 'realTimeButton',
                symbol: 'diamond',
                x: -62,
                symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                _titleKey: "realTimeButtonTitle",
                onclick: function() {
                    // handle change to real time
                    if ( enable_lastRoundsChart_realtime )
                    {
                        enable_lastRoundsChart_realtime = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enable_lastRoundsChart_realtime = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in simple way, but you can use renderer to prepare your own button and hover / pressed styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvpDk/

```
normalState = new Object();
    normalState.stroke_width = null;
    normalState.stroke = null;
    normalState.fill = null;
    normalState.padding = null;
    normalState.r = null;

    hoverState = new Object();
    hoverState = normalState;
    hoverState.fill = 'red';

    pressedState = new Object();
    pressedState = normalState;

    var custombutton = chart.renderer.button('button', 74, 10, function(){
        alert('aaa');
    },null,hoverState,pressedState).add();
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I tried your jFiddle example on Firefox - works perfect.
Same jFiddle on IE does not work :(